# Ubuntu & Fedora sharing with Samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, samba

How can I share files between a desktop PC( with Ubuntu) and a notebook(with Fedora) in the same network using samba? I tried to configure samba to both of them, but nothing?
On Fedora I configured Samba using the GUI(add a new user, name the server and so on).
Could someone give me a link to a good tutorial? I searched on google, but nothing good.

Comment: Why are you trying samba? It is better to use NFS to share between linux systems. Though we need a security consideration.

Comment: Can you [edit] and give us a bit more detail about what you did and where you got stuck?  The first page of `samba tutorial` in Google provides "good" tutorials, so perhaps you need more specific help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on both machines.

First, backup the existing smb.conf file:

```
sudo mv /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.old
```

Then put this in /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]
server string = Your computer's description
workgroup = Your workgroup name
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
name resolve order = bcast hosts wins
client lanman auth=Yes
wins support = yes

include = /etc/samba/smbshared.conf
```

And then in /etc/samba/smbshared.conf put this:

```
[Desktop] ; user="yourusername"
force user = yourusername
path = /path/to/share
writable = yes
public = yes
```